# How to create a new object instance in jsf?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xhtml

I would like to create a new entity instance in my jsf, bind the input values to the properties and pass the entire object to a method. Unfortunately, I am not able to create a new instance of an entity or bind the values to the properties in jsf. I created a small example to explain my issue:

The managed bean `BookCatalogBean` is a kind of controller and work as interface between view and model. The method `getNewBook` create a new instace of `Book`. The input values in the jsf should be bind to this object.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BookCatalogBeanimplements Serializable {
    private List<Book> availableBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public BookCatelogBean() {
        this.availableBooks.add(new Book(0, "Title", "Author"));
    }

    public Book getNewBook() {
        return new Book(this.getNewId());
    }

    public void add(Book book) {
    }

    public void update(Book book) {
    }

    public void delete(Book book) {
    }

    private long getNewId() {
        return this.availableBooks.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getId())).get().getId() + 1;
    }
}
```

In my view I would like to reuse the new instance of `Book` and bind the input values to the properties of the object. I tried to create a new instance with `<c:set />` but this did not work. My managed bean or method `bookCatelogBean.add` always receives an object with an empty (null) `title` and `author`.

```
<h:form class="form">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>
                <!-- Create and use a new instance ob `Book` -->
                <h:inputText value="#{newBook.title}" a:placeholder="Title"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{newBook.author}" a:placeholder="Autor"/>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>
                <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bookCatelogBean.add(newBook)}"/>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</h:form>
```

How could I create a new instance of `Book` in my jsf and bind the input values to it? What I am doing wrong?

*I am aware, that I can turn the entity `Book` into a managed bean with requested scope to create a single object per request, but I need multiple objects per request at different places. If I use `Book` with requested scope every `var="book"` has the same value.*

Comment: That's exactly not what I am looking for and not a duplicate.

Comment: I guees newBook is a ManagedBean too? Why you wan't to do that? Normally you should initialize the book in your BookCatalogBean (Book newBook = new Book();. Your values look like this: value="#{bookCatalogBean.newBook.title}" and in your add method you can do what you want with it (e.q. add it to the list) and then maybe set newBook = new Book(); to get a new instance of book to work with.

Comment: The duplciate clearly says to use `#{bookCatelogBean.newBook.title}` etc. How exactly is that not what you're looking for? In any case, nobody stops you from writing code the way you want yourself instead of the way recommended by experts.